# eliminar datos de un DataTable()

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

¿cómo puedo eliminar datos de `DataTable()`?, al instanciar

> var table = $('#sampleTable').DataTable();

me marca como error

> TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

¿existe una forma incluso de quitar la función? puesto que con la `<table>` solo, si se quitan los datos y lo pruebo con `DataTable()` ya no se quitan los datos

```
function data() {
var a = document.getElementById("fecha1").value;
var b = document.getElementById("fecha2").value;
//var table = $('#sampleTable').DataTable();
$("#sampleTable tr").slice(1).remove();
$("#load").css("display", "inline");
$.ajax({
    url: 'data',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {fin: a, ffn: b},
    success: function (rt) {for (var i = 1; i < rt.length; i++) {
            if (rt[i].id !== undefined) {
                rw = "<tr onclick='Dsc(" + rt[i].id + ")'><th>" + rt[i].nombreAg + "</th><th>" + rt[i].nInput + "</th><th>" + rt[i].tInput + "</th><th>" + rt[i].comision + "</th><th>" + rt[i].nOutput + "</th><th>" + rt[i].tOutput + "</th><th>" + rt[i].nCancel + "</th><th>" + rt[i].tCancel + "</th><th>" + rt[i].diff + "</th></tr>";
                $(".data").append(rw);
            }
        }
        $("#load").css("display", "none");
        $("#tb").append("<script type='text/javascript'>$('#sampleTable').DataTable({'language': {'url': '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json'},'bDestroy': true, 'aaSorting': [[0, 'desc']]});</script> ");
    }
});
```

**html**

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><div class="col-sm-4">Desde:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fecha1" name="fecha" required="true" value="${ant}"></div><div class="col-sm-4">Hasta:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fecha2" name="fecha" required="true" value="${hoy}"></div><div class="col-sm-3">.<input class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="buscar" onclick="data()" /></div></div>
<div id="tb" style="overflow-x: auto;padding-right: 15px;">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered data" id="sampleTable">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color: #00002f;color: #fff">
                <th>Agencia</th>
                <th># Recividos</th>
                <th>S/ Recivido</th>
                <th>S/ Comision</th>
                <th># Recividos</th>
                <th>S/ Entregado</th>
                <th>S/ Cancelados</th>                    
                <th># Cancelados</th>
                <th>S/ Diferencia</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>       
<div id="load" style="height: 100px">
    <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
</div>
<script src="../static/sjs/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/sjs/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#fecha1").datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
    $("#fecha2").datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
    data();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/sjs/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/sjs/plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aunque cambie la fecha, siguen los mismos datos

Comment: Puedes añadir el código de html y script. El error puede recaer en que llamas en el orden en el cual no es debido por eso te aparee ese error.

Comment: El error de `TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function`, es porque no haz cargado el script de Datetable, fíjate si redirecionaste  bien el script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En primer lugar segun tu codigo no estas cargando los datos en el `datatable` solo los estas incrustando en la pagina con `$(".data").append(rw);` , si bien es cierto que la libreria te lo muestra como un `datatable` estos son solo los `styles` es decir visualmente ha cargado los colores y las posiciones para las celdas cuando especificaste en el `class` agregaste  `class="table table-hover table-bordered data"`.

- Si necesitas cargar los datos en el `datatable`, a través de una llamada **ajax** podrias usar esta forma

`$('#sampleTable').DataTable( {
        "ajax": 'url/array.html'
});`

> Segun la version que tengas de [`datatables.js`](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

De otra forma deberás iniciar la `table` **despues**, de cargar los datos de la forma en la que lo haces ahora asi : `$('#sampleTable').DataTable();`.

> La function `DataTable()` permite "iniciar" un datatable.

Después de hacer esto entonces efectivamente deberías tener un `datatable` creado a partir del `table ("#sampleTable")` en tu pagina.

---

Si lo que quieres es obtener una instancia de ese `datatable` (*"una ves seguro de que este ha sido creado"*)
debes usar : `dataTable()`

```
if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#sampleTable')) 
    var table = $('#sampleTable').dataTable();
```

Entonces tendras una instancia del datatable en la variable `table`

> Como notaras la *function* `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable` te indica si un elemento es una instancia de `datatable`

Ahora la forma de eliminar una fila del datatable podria ser esta

```
table.row(rowReference).remove().draw(false);
```

segun la [documentacion](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove())

> NOTA : la importancia aqui recae en entender que `rowReference`, puede ser un elemento en la fila por lo que puedes usar `jquery` para buscar por una referencia por ejemplo, cuando cargas tu datatable (si es que lo sigues haciendo de esa forma), puedes asignarles un **id** unico a cada fila (tr) por lo que podrias buscarlo de esta forma `$("tr[id=" + idRow + "]")` , y tendrias algo como esto :

```
table .row($("tr[id=" + idRow + "]")).remove().draw(false);
```

recomiendo ver la documentacion de [`datatables.js`](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html), para que entiendas mejor.

Comment: Estoy en el segundo caso `$('#sampleTable').DataTable();` por eso probé `$("#sampleTable tr").slice(1).remove();` para refrescar toda la tabla, pero solo se acumulan los `row`, con tu validacion ya no sale `TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function`, ahora me sale error en `clear()` y `destroy()` , ¿tendrás alguna idea para esto?, el _DataTable funcionan sin problema ejm. buscar, ordenar.._

Comment: Podrías darme mas detalles sobre el error de clear() y destroy() ? no logro comprenderte.

Comment: segun su documentacion `var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table
 .clear()
 .draw();` o `table.destroy();` son para vaciar el datatable

Comment: Me refería a que **tipo de error aparece**, aunque por lo que veo en tu comentario nuevamente estas usando `.DataTable()`, en vez de `.dataTable()`, como lo explique en mi respuesta para obtener una instancia de el datatable.  `var table = $('#sampleTable').dataTable();`

Comment: Ok revise  su uso del la function `clear()` es cierto 2 cosas aqui.   1- `.DataTable()` no retorna la misma instancia del `datatable` que `.dataTable()`  por lo que para el uso de `clear()` si es necesario `.DataTable()`.  2- `.DataTable()`  funcionara solo si ya ha sido creada una instancia del `datatable` sobre ese elemento que obtienes por la id `($("#"))`, (amenos que le incluya configuración que es la inicialziacion normal ). en conclusion en su caso asegúrese de que el datatable ya ha sido creado antes de obtener una instancia de esta forma : `$('#example').DataTable();`

Answer (score 3):

la manera mas facil seria con javasript  aqui le dejo el otro link [eliminar fila de tabla html con Jquery o JS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9141/eliminar-fila-de-tabla-html-con-jquery-o-js)

aqui esta el ejemplo

http://jsbin.com/qucododoza/edit?html,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr id="fila0">
      <td>Columna 1</td>
      <td>Columna 2</td>
      <td>Columna 3</td>
      <td>Columna 4</td>
      <td>Columna 5</td>
      <td>Columna 6</td>
      <td><input type="button" onclick="eliminarFila(0);" value="Eliminar" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fila1">
      <td>Columna 1</td>
      <td>Columna 2</td>
      <td>Columna 3</td>
      <td>Columna 4</td>
      <td>Columna 5</td>
      <td>Columna 6</td>
      <td><input type="button" onclick="eliminarFila(1);" value="Eliminar" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fila2">
      <td>Columna 1</td>
      <td>Columna 2</td>
      <td>Columna 3</td>
      <td>Columna 4</td>
      <td>Columna 5</td>
      <td>Columna 6</td>
      <td><input type="button" onclick="eliminarFila(2);" value="Eliminar" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fila3">
      <td>Columna 1</td>
      <td>Columna 2</td>
      <td>Columna 3</td>
      <td>Columna 4</td>
      <td>Columna 5</td>
      <td>Columna 6</td>
      <td><input type="button" onclick="eliminarFila(3);" value="Eliminar" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fila4">
      <td>Columna 1</td>
      <td>Columna 2</td>
      <td>Columna 3</td>
      <td>Columna 4</td>
      <td>Columna 5</td>
      <td>Columna 6</td>
      <td><input type="button" onclick="eliminarFila(4);" value="Eliminar" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    function eliminarFila(index) {
        $("#fila" + index).remove();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```